# Angular best practice to validate overlapping date inputs via a datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

What would be the Angular way to validate overlapping dates(start and end dates).

I have a UI that has two datepicker inputs: one for start date and the other for end date, consider this a **row of dates**.

Users can add as many **rows of dates** as they want. However the next start date must be after the previous end date.

For example, if I have two rows of dates, the next start date must be after the previous end date and so on.

What would be the angular way to accomplish this?

My approach would be to create a directive that does this using `ngModel` and `$validators`. I can then iterate through the model and start comparing the end date with the next start date. I can then display the appropriate error message in the UI.

I am creating these **row of dates** with `ngRepeat` and using `ngMessages` directives to display error messages as well as `UI Bootstrap`'s datepicker directive.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I have not. I am trying to collect some ideas before blindly going straight to  implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a great community and I learned early on that you'll only get crickets if you don't provide what you have initially researched yourself and tried. Even if it is minimal. You should read this: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)